# Is assigning variable with Scope Resolution Operator(::) same as $this->variable?

Tags: php, class, variables

Just curious.

if I assign `self::$session = $reg->get('session');` in a `__construct` class, can the variable be used as the class' properties just like  `$this->session = $reg->get('session');`?

I have no idea how to test this. The only way I could test this is to make my entire framework in ruin by changing them all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just tried a bit around what is possible on the PHP shell (`php -a`).

```
php > class a { public $b; function __construct () { self::$b = 10; } }
php > $o = new a;
PHP Fatal error:  Access to undeclared static property: a::$b in php shell code on line 1

php > class a { public static $b; function __construct () { $this->b = 10; } }
php > $o = new a;
php > print $o->b;
10
php > print a::$b;
php > // outputs nothing (is still NULL)

php > class a { public static $b; function __construct () { self::$b = 10; } }
php > $o = new a;
php > print $o->b;
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: a::$b in php shell code on line 1

php > // doesn't print a value (basically NULL)
```

#### What we find out

- You cannot assign a non-static property like a static property (with `self::...`).
- You can assign a static property like a non-static property. But it creates a new implicit non-static public property instead of changing the value of the static property.
- You cannot access a static property like a non-static property.

#### Conclusion

No, you cannot switch between static and non-static accesses and writes.

Comment: Good answer. I was just going to say "No."

Comment: @IanBrindley This is right, but not giving the asker any deeper insight into it.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I was actually looking for a way to make something like `$this->session::$data['customer_id']` work

Comment: @user2002495 What do you try? `self::$session->data['customer_id']`?

Comment: yes, and a class is assigned to `self::$session`, data is the static variable in that class

Comment: `$class = get_class(self::$session); $class::$data['customer_id'];`?

Comment: `$this->session = $request->get('session'); $this->session::$data['customer_id']` that's what I tried now, still error

Comment: @user2002495 This is ambiguous to the parser: `($this->session)::$data` or `$this->(session::$data)`?

Comment: both, I think it's not possible?

Comment: Try: `$classname = $this->session = $request->get('session'); $classname::$data['customer_id'];`

Comment: yeah, that works :D Just wondering if later i could access the variable `$this->session` from other class using something like `$customer->session`? Thanks a lot by the way

Comment: You can, you'll only have to assign the class' name to a separate variable and use this when accessing the $data static property

Comment: @bwoebi yeah I could, thanks again, wish i could get you a beer

Answer (score 0):

Before I start this, you could test this easily with an online codepad tool as well, but I felt it might be better to actually explain what's going on.

Let's assume you have this class, based on what you have described:

```
class MyClass
{
    private static $session;

    public function __construct($reg)
    {
        self::$session = $reg->get('session');
    }
}
```

The expression `self::$session` references a class variable which is shared amongst **all** instances of `MyClass`.

Let's change the class to the following:

```
class MyClass
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct($reg)
    {
        $this->session = $reg->get('session');
    }
}
```

Now, the expression `$this->session` references an *instance* variable, which is not shared with **any** other instance of `MyClass`.

Because of this difference, they can't be used interchangeably and you will have to make a decision based on your functional design.